# What does this type of training help and set me up for based on my line of work?

Tags: career-development

I've worked as a DevOps engineer for about 6 years now. I love the field and am content with the work that I do. I realize that from the number of years experience I have, I have absolutely no soft skills. My boss has asked me to look into Project Management training and I can appreciate looking into this as it will help me do my job much better. My question is: What would Project Management really set me up for long term? Is this to advance myself as an engineer or is this more of a management skill? Ideally, Id like to stay in Engineering and hopefully see myself as a Principal Engineer one day. Can training for Project Management (PMP, Scrum Master training, etc.) get me to that point? Would this be a benefit of me to take this kind of training? And if so, what are the pros to this?

Comment: Curious to know why its down-voted with no reason given..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would have loved my developers to have more project management knowledge. Even if you never work as a project manager, for you to understand about dependencies, risks, critical path, the steps that happen before and after the "dev" part, how to communicate progress in a way everyone can understand, and all the rest of the things a PM should know -- that will make you a much better developer and engineer.

That said, your boss may have a different reason for suggesting this course. They may see you moving into management, or they may just have a training budget to use up and this is something on offer you haven't already taken. By accepting this course you may be signalling a willingness to take a particular career path -- or it may mean nothing at all. I suggest you **ask your boss** why this particular course comes to mind and what your boss thinks the benefit to the team will be of you taking it.

Answer (score 1):

> Ideally, Id like to stay in Engineering and hopefully see myself as a Principal Engineer one day.

I don't see Project Manager as a step towards Principal Engineer. You would learn some useful skills, but many are irrelevant. As you progress in responsibility in Engineering you learn a more focused skillset.

One issue I have found is that when you stop focusing on a core skillset it can be difficult to go back to it. At the very least you normally would need to change companies and possibly take a job which is a step backwards.

But I suggest you read up on Project Management, it may appeal to you, and it's a solid career.